# mysql_num_rows and SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Is it safe to use this code ?

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE nick='asd'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($check);
```

I just need number of rows. id is AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Is this the final statement? I mean, you dont want to put a variable in replace of 'asd' ? Then you are safe!

Comment: do you get your id from user input?

Comment: use mysqli or use PDO mysql_ is deprecated.

Comment: `num_rows` is irrelevant, that's not where injection occurs. [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: I will use PHP variables instead of asd

Comment: how do you generate the php variables? do you get it from post or get ? put your complete code in your question

Comment: variable will come from SESSION. I have no more code .... it is just an idea that will come true but i want to know the best way and the easiest way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 'asd' is a constant and not related to any (user) input, then yes it is safe.

Otherwise you should replace it with bind a variable and use prepared statements or at least escape it properly. (But it is easy to forget escaping, so it is a better practice to try to use bind variables instead.)

Comment: The question is: "Is it safe to use this code ?" Or Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are correct. He gave two correct answers - is `asd` a constant, yes it's safe. If it's not, then no, it's not safe.

Comment: yes question is as you said ... so escape inpus should be enought ?

Comment: If you do it properly everywhere then yes, escaping is enough. But generally it is better to use prepared statements.

Comment: and if i use only mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table") and then mysql_num_rows it will be safe ? so i mean to count all rows

Comment: Sql injection is only relevant if you insert user input to your queries. So constant queries are fine.

Answer (score 1):

NO. Absolutely not.

First of all, read up on [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli). The i stands for improved. Secondly, use prepared statements. This prevents injection. Read up on that [here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli).

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "DATABASE-NAME", "DATABASE-USER", "DATABASE-PASS");
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `nick` = ?");
$check->bind_param('s', $nickVar);
$check->execute();
```

Don't take the easy way out. Keep doing things safe until it comes naturally. I used to be all about quick hacks, quickly get it to work, quickly write some things down, but in the end, it's best to get used to good practice.

Comment: i wanted to avoid  to use PDO here ... i´m able to use it but it is too long I think to use it just to count rows.

Comment: Define 'too long'. A few more lines definitely are worth the vulnerabilities you avoid by using PDO.